# Compare two tables and get the number(count) of similarities in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have two tables. I want to get the number of items similar to each other.

table1:

`reference_id`-`correct`

1 - ibmiz1

2 - ibmih5

3 - im7

table2:

`sub_id`-`user_submited`

1 - ibmiz17

2 - im3

3 - ibmih5

In the above example, there is only one similarity: **ibmih5** ---> $count=1

Please help me to get the number of similarities by using the MySQL command

Comment: Similar or the same? And what do you have so far?

Comment: @jeroen Just like the example. The values are in the string ----> same

Comment: @B001ᛦ - the column names are `reference_id`-`correct` and `sub_id`-`user_submited`

Comment: my bad @RamRaider .. I need more coffee today :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376082/how-can-i-select-similar-rows-in-two-different-tables-in-mysql-is-it-possible

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking can be done using a simple WHERE from two tables

```
SELECT
    count(*) as cnt 
FROM
    table1,
    table2
WHERE
    table1.correct = table2.user_submitted;
```

Comment: Whenever you see you have more than 1 table in your `FROM` statement it is time to better use a `JOIN`statement